# Tool to convert a sequence of numbered PNG files to an animated GIF?

Tags: software-recommendation, png

I've created a series of small PNG files using Blender and I was wondering if there was a tool (preferably in the repos.) that would convert them to an animated GIF.

One extra stipulation: the tool needs to also be able to set the background color of the GIF to a specified color since the PNG files have an alpha channel and I don't want the GIF to be transparent.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, using `imagemagick`s `convert` tool:

```
convert   -delay 20   -loop 0   frame*.png   animated.gif
```

This will take all of the source frames and will make them into one animated GIF image.  The -delay 20 argument will cause a 20 hundredths of a second delay between each frame, and the -loop 0 will cause the gif to loop over and over again.

As for setting the background color for the gif, that can be done with the `background` and `flatten` flags:

```
convert -delay 20 -loop 0 frame*.png -background white -flatten animated.gif
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753190/programmatically-generate-video-or-animated-gif-in-python) you can use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) or a [Python script](http://www.somethinkodd.com/oddthinking/2005/12/06/python-imaging-library-pil-and-animated-gifs/#comment-197921).