# Are there any pieces of software available on Ubuntu for the conversion of a series of image files into an animated gif file?

Tags: software-recommendation, image-processing

Before you mention this question [Tool to convert a sequence of numbered PNG files to an animated GIF?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43763/tool-to-convert-a-sequence-of-numbered-png-files-to-an-animated-gif) I would like to say I'm a total noob when it comes to ubuntu (I know I have 1375 rep but I have since gone back to Windows and have only just now returned and my memory is very fussy) and ImageMagick doesn't seem to have a convert tool any more. I'm used to using PhotoScape on Windows and I rather like its set up so if anyone knows an alternative on Ubuntu that's similar that'd be much appreciated.